# Early results venue?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, publication

Not sure if this is appropriate but there were similar questions that I checked so I'll try.
I've been working on a known problem in the number theory and may have an interesting early result.
The issue is that I work in a different field (have publications) so the terminology, format, style, the flow etc can be off and for these reasons I'm reluctant to submit it formally to save the reviewer's and my time.
So is there a venue / forum e.g. a field-specific preprint server where it can be checked by the specialists in the field?

Comment: You might want to consider [arXiv.org](https://arxiv.org/), hosted by Cornell University.  It operates as a digital preprint service in a wide range of fields.  You will like need an email address with an institutional affiliation to post papers there.  That said it sounds like it is more of a job for an editor (addressing format, style, etc.) than a "crowd sourcing" job.

Comment: "A different field" meaning what? ... Another branch of mathematics? Should be no problem, papers will have the same "format style flow".  Or a non-mathematics field? That is a problem; you will likely be seen as a crank.  Posting to arXiv is good.  But note that even cranks do that.

Comment: Non-mathematics field, computer science, machine learning. Indeed the concern is to be taken for such wasting everybody's time.